# LibGDX - Move camera not working

Tags: java, libgdx, camera

I'm starting with LibGDX and I loving it so far, but I have found some troubles and I'm getting a little frustrated. I've searched a lot for a solution and tried many things, but nothing seems to work. What I want to accomplish is basically a 2d map with a rts-like camera, in other words, a map/world bigger than the viewport where I can move the camera freely. The problem is I can't make the camera move, and I'm not even sure if my world is bigger than my viewport. How can I get these two things done? I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure what it is. Any help would be really appreciated.

These are my classes:

**GameMain**

```
public class GameMain extends Game {

private SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    ScreenManager.getInstance().initialize(this);
    ScreenManager.getInstance().showScreen(ScreenEnum.WORLD);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();
}

public SpriteBatch getBatch() {
    return this.batch;
}
}
```

**AbstractScreen**

```
public abstract class AbstractScreen extends Stage implements Screen {
protected AbstractScreen() {
    super(new ScreenViewport(new OrthographicCamera()));
}

// Subclasses must load actors in this method
public abstract void buildStage();

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // Clear screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Calling to Stage methods
    super.act(delta);
    super.draw();
}

@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override public void hide() {}
@Override public void pause() {}
@Override public void resume() {}
}
```

**ScreenEnum**

```
public enum ScreenEnum {

WORLD {
    public AbstractScreen getScreen(GameMain game, Object... params) {
        return new WorldScreen(game);
    }
};

public abstract AbstractScreen getScreen(GameMain game, Object... params);
}
```

**ScreenManager**

```
public class ScreenManager {

// Singleton: unique instance
private static ScreenManager instance;

// Reference to game
private GameMain game;

// Singleton: private constructor
private ScreenManager() {
    super();
}

// Singleton: retrieve instance
public static ScreenManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ScreenManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

// Initialization with the game class
public void initialize(GameMain game) {
    this.game = game;
}

// Show in the game the screen which enum type is received
public void showScreen(ScreenEnum screenEnum, Object... params) {

    // Get current screen to dispose it
    Screen currentScreen = game.getScreen();

    // Show new screen
    AbstractScreen newScreen = screenEnum.getScreen(game, params);
    newScreen.buildStage();
    game.setScreen(newScreen);

    // Dispose previous screen
    if (currentScreen != null) {
        currentScreen.dispose();
    }
}
}
```

**WorldScreen**

```
public class WorldScreen extends AbstractScreen {

private GameMain game;
private Texture map;

public WorldScreen(GameMain game) {
    this.game = game;
    map = new Texture("sprites/maps/map.jpg");
}

@Override
public void buildStage() {

}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);

    game.getBatch().begin();
    game.getBatch().draw(map, 0, 0);
    game.getBatch().end();
    this.getCamera().translate(+500, +500, 0);
    this.getCamera().update();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

I debugged the camera and it's changing its value position, but it's not being reflected in the screen.

Also, is there a way to prevent the map texture from being scaled when resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not updating the `projectionMatrix` of the `SpriteBatch`. You have to update the projection matrix otherwise the batch will not know what do display on screen.

To fix this simply add `game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(this.getCamera().combined);` before your `batch.begin()` in your `WorldScreen` and anywhere else you use the batch.

Your update should now look like this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);

    // Important line right here
    game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(this.getCamera().combined);
    game.getBatch().begin();
    game.getBatch().draw(map, 0, 0);
    game.getBatch().end();
    this.getCamera().translate(+500, +500, 0);
    this.getCamera().update();
}
```